# Some site images are not displayed on mobile

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a WordPress site and some of the images on my site are not displayed on mobile.
My site is WordPress and I use the rocket plugin, but there are no problems with the mobile settings
[image: my site]

my site : [farazito.ir](https://farazito.ir/)

Answer (score 0):

The image is not available. check image link
https://farazito.ir/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/scale_1200-500x286.webp

Answer (score 0):

Sir your images are not exist in wordpress directory or renamed.
edit your homepage with elementor and select again these images.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).